# Can I force a node to send its node object to chef server mid-recipe execution?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I'm doing this in a recipe:

```
tag('mytag')
nodeobjs = search(:node, 'tags:mytag')
```

On first run on a node search() won't find it (until it runs again).

I know the nodes build a local copy of their node object before sending it too the server. Is it possible to force the node to propagate its node object mid-recipe execution?

I could obviously tag the node in a different recipe that runs before this recipe in the run list, but I was just curious if it is possible to call tag('mytag') and have that change immediately propagated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes but really really don't. You'll need to add a check for the local node that looks at local data, otherwise even with a `node.save` you have indexer lag to deal with.